# Screen goes in black when enter savingmode

Tags: gpu

Hello I an issue when laptop go to save-mode.

The laptopp freezes after many attempts to enter save-mode/log-out-mode.
I use 2 exstra screen + the laptopp. One is connected to HDMI on is connected to a Mini-DisplayPort. *(The USB 3.2 Gen C port is not in use)*. The laptop has only problem with saving-mode when the two other screen are connected. When it freezes all tre screen go black and it want start up again.

The laptop is an *MSI Alpha 17 A4ADE* with two GPU.(https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/Alpha-17-A4DX?sub_product=Alpha-17-A4DE#down-bios)

GPU0/1: AMD Radeon RX 5600M.

GPU1/2: AMD Radeon (TM) Graphics.

Best regards

Gunnar